# Localization of audio-files failed (AV-Audio Player)

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I want to localize the audio-files of my application. I doing this the same way as images, that means

1. select mp3-file
2. click on localize
3. Choose main
4. Add some language for example german
5. File is duplicated in de.lproj folder
6. overwrite this file with the german-audio-file (named exactly like the first one)

Now I clean and build it to the simulator, but the simulator is only playing the base-audio-file every time. (Also if the simulator languague is GERMAN!)
I delete the app a view times on the simulator and build it again, but there is only the base-audio-file playing.

My code for playing the audio-file:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/crunch_wdh8.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer.delegate = (id)self;

//NSLog(@"Entered the callback function");

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.delegate = (id)self;

    if (audioPlayer== nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error );
} else {
    [audioPlayer play];    }
```

How can I fix this??

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the wrong initalisation of the AVAudioPlayer.
This wasn't working with localized files!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/crunch_wdh8.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

Here I found good tutorial for localize audio files with xcode:
[Localization of audio-files in Xcode](http://bikinibody-app.com/?p=103)